# Como quitar las dos columnas que forman el estilo "Articulo" de LATEX para una sola página

Tags: latex

Estoy haciendo un artículo con dos columnas en Latex y en los Apéndices en vez de ponerse el título y seguidamente la imagen, se ponen 2 títulos en una pagina y luego las imágenes en las otras. No es problema de tamaños porque he probado con todos y nada, también especificando [h!] y [htb]. Adjunto fotos de como está ahora y como me gustaría que estuviese (señalado en rojo en la imagen):

**Página solo con el título:**

[image: página solo con el título]

**Página solo con la imagen:**

[image: página solo con la imagen]

Código:

```
\subsection{Casos de Uso}
\label{casosuso}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/CasosUsoAdmin.png}
\caption{Diagrama de casos de uso - Administrador.}
\label{casoadmin}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/casosUsoUser.png}
\caption{Diagrama de casos de uso - Usuario.}
\label{casouser}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\newpage 
\subsection{Diagrama E-R}
\label{diagramaer}
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/DiagramaER.png}   
    \caption{Diagrama E-R de la Base de Datos.}
    \label{er}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta corta es que no se puede usando `figure*`, debido a que en Wikipedia ([LaTeX/Floats, Figures and Captions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions), Sección: *Wide figures in two-column documents*) se menciona lo siguiente:

> A bad point of those environments is that **they can be placed only at the top of the page or on their own page** [...]

### Posible Solución

Una opción viable que encontré fue ajustar *manualmente* las imágenes para obtener el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Código

Esto fue usando:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % No es necesario, solo para generar texto aleatorio

\begin{document}
    \subsection{Casos de Uso}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{minipage}{2\linewidth}
            \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/Dia1}
                \caption{Diagrama de casos de uso - Administrador.}
            \end{minipage}\hfill
            \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/Dia2}
                \caption{Diagrama de casos de uso - Usuario.}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \textbf{Texto del Caso de Uso}\\ % No es necesario
    \lipsum[1-2] % No es necesario
    \newpage
    \subsection{Diagrama E-R}
    \begin{figure}
        \vspace*{7.5cm} % Ajuste manual
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/Dia3}
        \caption{Diagrama E-R de la Base de Datos.}
        \label{er}
    \end{figure}
    \textbf{Texto del Diagrama E-R}\\ % No es necesario
    \lipsum[4] % No es necesario
\end{document}
```